# Android EditBox TextWatcher fires too much

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, onchange, textwatcher

I am trying to process an input character when given, clear the box, and be ready to process another.

The app uses an EditBox which always has a max of 1 character.  When the user enters a new character, a listener will fire.  The afterTextChanged method of that listener (a TextWatcher) processes the entered character and clears the text.  After that, it clears the textbox, and leaves it ready to listen for the next one.  However, it continues to fire after that.  I try setting a flag to only process every other firing, but sometimes it is devious and fires an odd number of times and flips the flag wrong.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    if (arg0.length() > 0) {
        //if (mToggle)
        {
            act.checkText(arg0.toString().substring(arg0.length() - 1));
            text.setText("");
        }
        mToggle = !mToggle; // to catch extra fire-off
    }
}
```

mToggle is a property variable of the TextWatcher implementation.

1) Why the multiple firings?

2) What do I need to do here instead?

Thanks much,
Nathan

Comment: The answer to your first question is literally [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html): *" It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback [`afterTextChanged()`], **but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively**."*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why is

```
if (mToggle)
```

commented out?

Secondly, you should only set mToggle to false in your if:

```
if (mToggle) {

      act.checkText(arg0.toString().substring(arg0.length() - 1));
      text.setText("");
      mToggle = false; // to catch extra fire-off

}
```

Then, somewhere else in code (when the user clicks on another editBox, you can set mToggle back to true. That will allow your if (mToggle) condition run one time again.